# Can't open word document with my code

Tags: c#, ms-word

I tried this code to change word document, but after creating it word stops working and I can not understand why.

```
        try
        {
            string filename = Console.ReadLine();
            string openfile = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/" + filename + ".docx";
            FileStream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(openfile);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
            string texti = Console.ReadLine();
            writer.Write(texti);
            writer.Close();
            //string information =  "Hello Persistent file ";
            //File.WriteAllText("C:/Users/user/Desktop/ForC#.docx", information);
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.Write("incorrect name");
        }
```

Comment: Because that is not a valid Word document...

Comment: You can't just alter the Word file without using an API. For example, this assebly Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.dll

Answer (score 1):

A Word document - no matter what type - is not a text file. The documents with a docx extension are ZIP packages of XML (and sometimes binary) files that define the Word document. The Word application is required in order to view these as documents. If you open and edit them as text files they become corrupted.

A docx file can be changed by code by using automation (the "Word.Interop") to manipulate the Word application. OR it can be changed by using programming tools that can work with Zip packages (System.IO.Packaging, for instance) and XML files. Microsoft created the Open XML SDK which abstracts working with the Zip package and XML content, making it more intuitive for developers. Generally, if you want to change a Word document without interacting with a user the Open XML SDK is the preferred way to go.

Information about working with Office in the .NET Framework can be found in the following article, which contains lots of links to more detailed information:
    https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/311452

More about the Open XML SDK: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx